# OnetoOne Hibernate Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

In a One To One mapping, I wrote the following lines of code.

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name="property", value= "post"))
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
public int getContent_id() {
    return content_id;
}
```

What is the significance of **@Parameter(name="property", value= "post")**. If I don't write that line I'm getting an error

*Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=in.codejava.personal.model.Content]*

**EDIT**

When I changed the value = "post" to anything else like value="post123" etc it works. But it doesn't work when I completely remove that. Partial Code http://pastebin.com/CjEpqtXV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows telling the generator from which property the ID must be extracted (in this case: "post"). An entity could have several OnetoOne associations. You need to tell it which one of them contains the ID of your entity.

Note that this generator can be replaced by a standard JPA annotation on the OneToOne association containing the ID: [@MapsId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html). The Hibernate documentation [recommends its usage](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5617) rather than the foreign generator.

Comment: @jn-nizet i changed value="post" to value = "post1". it still executes properly. how?

Comment: No idea. That looks quite strange.

Comment: I tested again but post1 also worked. Anyways Following is the code. Can you help me in optimizing it. http://pastebin.com/CjEpqtXV. Just few lines. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second link I included in my answer shows how to use MapsId for your situation. Follow the link.